# Second Highest Salary using JPA method

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I recently faced an interview question to find 2nd highest salary from MySQL table.

I gave the query,

```
select Distinct salary from Employee order by salary desc limit 1 offset 2.
```

But he asked me to write the same with JPA in build method queries..

I was able to guess like findBySalaryGreaterThan..

Not able to get the correct answer..

How to write JPA in build method query for second highest salary..

Comment: You can use like: `findBySalaryOrderByDesc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got this basic query in JPA?

So just add pagination to that query, set the page size to 1 and get the second page.